# Does .NET 3.5+ use type inference on DataRow.Item property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, type-inference

I was working with some legacy code today and noticed something strange.  We have some old ADO .NET code that's reading some data from a database into a `DataTable`.

At some point in time, the following code

```
SubscriptionDT.Rows[0]["LastShownBenefits"].ToString().Substring(0, 10)
```

returned

```
2001-01-01
```

However, now it returns

```
1/1/2001 1
```

If I quickwatch `SubscriptionDT.Rows[0]["LastShownBenefits"]` it seems to be able to infer that the type is of `System.DateTime`.  (This column is a `DateTime` in the database).  However, I have a feeling that before we upgraded the project to .NET 3.5, this was probably recognized as a `System.Object`.  Obviously, calling `.ToString()` returns different results between the two...

My questions are:

1)  Am I right about type inference?  I thought this might be the case since the `var` keyword was introduced in .NET 3.5.

2)  Is there any documentation available for this change (or similar changes)?  I've been searching MSDN for some time now, but haven't been able to find anything.

Comment: What is this column defined as in your xsd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you are not right. The reason is that now a different locale is being used for whatever reason.
That's why you should always specify the culture in a call to `ToString` to avoid exactly this type of problem.

To be clear: This has absolutely nothing to do with type inference. The object was a boxed `DateTime` in .NET 2.0 and it still is a boxed `DateTime` in .NET 3.5.

The `var` keyword is strictly a compile time feature. There is no difference in the resulting IL between code using the `var` keyword and code that explicitly specifies the type of a variable, e.g.:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
// results in exactly the same IL code as:
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Any ideas about *how* the locale could be different now?  This code has never specified one in the `.ToString` call; is it possible for it to change over time due to other factors?

Comment: @JeremyWiggins: Yes, that is possible. As the documentation of `DateTime.ToString` states, it uses the current culture to format the string representation. The current culture can be set by any code in your application. As you can see, when you compare the [.NET 2.0 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.80).aspx) with the [.NET 3.5 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k494fzbf(v=vs.90).aspx) you see that it still uses the "G" format specifier along with the CurrentCulture, so no breaking change here either.

Comment: I suspect that somewhere in your application the CurrentCulture is being set.

Comment: You're right.  It turns out that some while back, a 3rd party plugin was installed that sets `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JeremyWiggins: Good job finding that plugin that fast! :-)